# how i can zoom directly to my current location in android application maps

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng bangalore = new LatLng(12.9667, 77.5667);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bangalore).title("Bengaluru"));
    float zoomLevel = 12;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bangalore, zoomLevel));
}
```

that code zooming to bangalore area but i need for my current location

Comment: get your current location and put the zoom code in that in this code you are giving the lat long of banglore that's why it showing the location on banglore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code      **location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()**  used to get current location

```
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                if (location != null)
                {
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your current location in this function where you have placed your marker.

```
private void moveToCurrentLocation(LatLng currentLocation)
  {   
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation,15));
  // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
 // animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   LatLngBounds.Builder   builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

  mMap.getMap().setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                   LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLatitude());
                   builder.include(latlng);

                   LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                   int padding = getScreenWidth(activity) / 10;
                   CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                   mMap.getMap().animateCamera(cu);
                }

             }
          });

public static int getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
      Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      Point size = new Point();
      display.getSize(size);
      return size.x;
   }
```